# get child id from parent javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have the script bellow and i want to get the id of the child removed

```
 <div class="right respleft">
        <div class="section-title" id="divin">Ajout d'un champ</div>
        <form class="tiny_form" id="form-step2">
            <input type="text" id="fiel" placeholder="Nom du champ" /><br/>
    <select class="form-control" id="champs">
</select>
         <a href="#" id="add_btn" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a><br/>
            <div id="extender"></div>

        </form>

    </div>

    <div class="sep seppage"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="bottom-submit" class="inner clear">
        <input type="submit" class="page-next center btn btn-lg btn-default" value="Créer" />
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script>

        //add input
        $('a#add_btn').click(function () {
            var x = document.getElementById("fiel");
            var selected= x.value;
            var c = document.getElementById("champs");
            // var option = document.createElement("option");
            var strUser = document.getElementById("champs").value;
            var valChamps=document.getElementById("fiel").value;
            $('<p><input type="text" class="highlight_orange" name="items[]" id="' + strUser+ '" value="' + valChamps+ '" />' +
                    '<a class="delete" href="#step2" id="' + strUser + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></p>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#extender');

            c.remove(c.selectedIndex);
            i++;
            return false;
        });


        //fadeout selected item and remove
        $("#form-step2").on('click', '.delete', function () {

            var item = $(this).closest('input');
            var id = item.attr('id');
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () {

                $(this).empty();
                return false;
            });
        });


        function addList(){
    var select = document.getElementById("champs");
    for(var i = 100; i > 0; --i) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text =  'champ libre '+i;
        option.value =i;
    select.add(option, 0);
    }
    }
addList();

    </script>
```

my problems is how to get the id of the removed input text after clicking on remove button.

this is  picture of the output
[output](https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfl1/v/t1.0-9/11953189_792531824189627_2683590049512597655_n.jpg?oh=4e5b8b6808726f7b94f3646d8b162fed&oe=5636F32D)

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery with document.getElementById?

Comment: document.getElementByID to get the id of the selected index in dropdown list, and the jquery to add an input text or remove it

Comment: document.getElementById gets an element BY its id. But jQuery does this  `$('#the-id')` which is why I ask why you mix them

Comment: I will correct it by using just jquery, but what interest me is the id of the removed item  //fadeout selected item and remove
    $("#form-step2").on('click', '.delete', function () {

        $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () {


            $(this).empty();
            return false;
        });
    });

Comment: Someone may have answered it. I couldn't see from your code what was removed, except c which is the element with ID "champs"

Comment: I've edited my questions, you can see the full code and the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute()` function:

```
// your stuff     
var myId = c.getAttribute("id");
c.remove(c.selectedIndex);
// more stuff
```

### EDIT

Maybe you need it here:

```
//fadeout selected item and remove
$("#form-step2").on('click', '.delete', function () {

    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () {

        var myId = $(this).attr('id');

        $(this).empty();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Be more specific please

### EDIT2

That's the solution:

```
//fadeout selected item and remove
$("#form-step2").on('click', '.delete', function () {

    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () {

        var myId = $(this).find('input[type=text]').attr('id');

        $(this).empty();
        return false;
    });
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/vWPJf/57/

Comment: But c = `document.getElementById("champs")` so in that code, myId = 'champs'

Comment: no, when clicking on the remove button, I wanna to get the ID of the removed input tex

Comment: see this example, http://jsfiddle.net/vWPJf/  when clicking on remove button, I wanna to get the id of it

Comment: I'll give you the complete source code  in the answer

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/vWPJf/57/ See this fiddle to view working. I've updated my answer

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was hard to understand. You can upvote the answer :)

Comment: I have just 8 reputation, I can't upvote the answers

Comment: I give you a vote in the question. I guess it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can use siblings method to get the id of input element

```
//fadeout selected item and remove
$("#form-step2").on('click', '.dynamic-link', function () {
    var myId = $(this).siblings('input[type=text]').attr('id');
    alert(myId)
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () {

        $(this).empty();
        return false;
    });
});
```